# Load from CSV File to Hive Table with Sqoop?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Is it possible to load a hive table from CSV file with help of Sqoop?

Answer (score 4):

[Sqoop](https://blogs.apache.org/sqoop/entry/apache_sqoop_overview) is not meant for that and I don't think it can solve your requirement. Sqoop is to import or export data between Hadoop and RDBMS.

For your case, you don't need sqoop, load the CSV file from HDFS or local to hive table. Below is the syntax for it.

```
LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs_file_or_directory_path' [OVERWRITE] INTO TABLE tablename
  [PARTITION (partcol1=val1, partcol2=val2 ...)]
```