# Command to import data from CSV to Avro table using sqoop

Tags: hive, bigdata, sqoop, hue

I have a csv file named `test.csv` on my HDFS.

I have created an Avro table (avro_test) using Hue with the same column names as the csv file. I want to use a `sqoop` command to put the csv elements in the Avro table.

What sqoop command will achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqoop is meant to load/transfer data between RDBMS and Hadoop. You can just insert the CSV data into the avro table you have created.

Please refer below link.
[Load from CSV File to Hive Table with Sqoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48557322/load-from-csv-file-to-hive-table-with-sqoop)

Comment: thanks. But is there any other way to do it with sqoop? 
Plus, when I did it with load data and then tried to display my table (select * from avro_tab), I got a long ERROR that starts with Bad status for Request TFetchResultsReq. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you please update the question with Table create statement, Sample CSV data and the error message that you are getting? Thanks.